# I am getting file_get_contents returning SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate

Tags: php, linux, centos7, file-get-contents

I'm getting the following error when I use file_get_contents with a URL from another server.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /home/test/public_html/.....

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/test/public_html/...... on line 24

Warning: file_get_contents(https://......): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/test/public_html/......php on line 24
```

This is my 4th VPS. The first 3 work absolutely fine but this one for some reason gives the above error. The setup on this VPS is identical.

Notes:

- allow_url_fopen is On
- The https on the target server is fine
- SSLv3 have been disabled on the target server due to it being deprecated.

It works when I use:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
   "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
         "verify_peer_name"=>false,
   ),
);
```

But some plugins use file_get_contents and I can't modify it due to updates.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Can you check and compare the contents of `openssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath` on your good and bad servers? https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php

Comment: A comment from another question might have solved my problem using `stream_context_set_default($arrContextOptions);` but for some reason after 3 days the server is working fine now without using the above. Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i also gone through similar situation [this link might belp](https://insidert.medium.com/fix-curl-error-60-in-wamp-server-a0ffff8dbb29)